# How to use ctools modal to popup some fields of a node on node view?

Tags: chaos-tool-suite, nodes, javascript

I want when a user is viewing a node, some of the node fields will be shown as a popup (without any buttons). How can I do it?

Thank You!

Comment: "without any buttons" - how they will be opened?

Comment: I mean with no buttons on the popup so it does not have to be a form

Comment: Can you describe a little bit more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that there is no codeWriting service here, but I can try to explain (with example) the process (not a universal way.. Will work only with the content the same type and same structure (suppose we have a content type with `body`, `field_description` and `field_something`)):

- You need to customize (override) template of the content type:

**example** (node--MY_CONTENT_TYPE.tpl.php):

```
<div id="node-<?php print $node->nid; ?>" class="<?php print $classes; ?> clearfix"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
  <div class="body-field">
    <?php print render($content['body']); ?>
  </div>


  <div class="description-field">
    <?php print ctools_modal_text_button(t('Click to see DescriptionField'), 'show-as-a-popup/' . $node->nid .'/field_description/nojs', t('DescriptionField'), 'ctools-modal-custom-modal-style'); ?>
  </div>


  <div class="something-field">
    <?php print ctools_modal_text_button(t('Click to see SomethingField'), 'show-as-a-popup/' . $node->nid .'/field_something/nojs', t('SomethingField'), 'ctools-modal-custom-modal-style'); ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

- Create [custom module](https://drupal.org/developing/modules/7)
- Create a function in `my_module.module` file which includes ctools' libraries and sends javascript settings:

example:

```
function _myModuleIncludesModal() {
  static $added = FALSE;
  if ($added == FALSE) {
    $added = TRUE;

    ctools_include('modal');
    ctools_include('ajax');
    ctools_modal_add_js();

    $customModalStyle = array(
      'custom-modal-style' => array(
        'modalSize' => array(
          'type' => 'fixed',
          'width' => 800,
          'height' => 'auto',
          'addWidth' => 20,
          'addHeight' => 20,
          'contentRight' => 20,
          'contentBottom' => 20,
        ),
        'modalOptions' => array(
          'opacity' => (float) 0.6,
          'background-color' => '#000000',
        ),
        'closeText' => 'Close',
        'loadingText' => 'Loading...',
        'animation' => 'fadeIn',
        'animationSpeed' => 'fast',
      ),
    );

    drupal_add_js($customModalStyle, 'setting');
  }
}
```

- Implement [hook_menu()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) hook:

example:

```
function my_module_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['show-as-a-popup/%node/%/%ctools_js'] = array(
    'title' => 'Node Field',
    'page callback' => 'nodeFieldPopupCallback',
    'page arguments' => array(1, 2, 3),
    'access callback' => 'user_access',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  return $items;
}
```

- Create a callback function:

example:

```
function nodeFieldCallback($node, $fieldType, $js = NULL) {
  if (!$js) {
    drupal_access_denied();
    drupal_exit();
  }

  ctools_include('modal');
  ctools_include('ajax');

  $nodeWrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);

  $output = $nodeWrapper->{$fieldType}->value();

  $return[] = ctools_modal_command_display(t('PoPUp'), $output);
  print ajax_render($return);
  drupal_exit();
}
```

- Finally call our `_myModuleIncludesModal()` in "specific" node pages:

example (template.php):

```
function MY_THEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  if($variables['type'] == 'MY_CONTENT_TYPE') {
    _myModuleIncludesModal();
  }
}
```

Modal settings/options, templating and throbber templating can be found in `ctools' help` directory;
Don't forget to flush the cache;

Comment: @RoniGal you need to install [Entity API](https://drupal.org/project/entity) to be able to use `entity_metadata_wrapper` function..

Comment: I know. Thank you for the guide. I had to changed a little bit of the code but you gave me the direction. Thanks!